# Creating multiple CSV files using SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv, nested-loops

I have a Table1 below in SQL.

```
ID | Provider | AdviserName   | PolicyNumber |
---|----------|---------------|--------------|
1  | Asgard   | John Smith    | A1           |
2  | Asgard   | Andrew Bailey | A2           |
3  | BT       | Tony Saw      | B1           |
4  | BT       | Greg Lee      | B2           |
5  | BT       | Jenny Main    | B3           |
6  | Zurich   | Beth Bond     | Z1           |
7  | Zurich   | Fang Li       | Z2           |
8  | Zurich   | Garry Low     | Z3           |
```

I need to export this table to .CSV (Microsoft Excel) and split between each provider.

Agard.csv

```
ID | Provider | AdviserName   | PolicyNumber |
---|----------|---------------|--------------|
1  | Asgard   | John Smith    | A1           |
2  | Asgard   | Andrew Bailey | A2           |
```

BT.csv

```
ID | Provider | AdviserName   | PolicyNumber |
---|----------|---------------|--------------|
3  | BT       | Tony Saw      | B1           |
4  | BT       | Greg Lee      | B2           |
5  | BT       | Jenny Main    | B3           |
```

Zurich.csv

```
ID | Provider | AdviserName   | PolicyNumber |
---|----------|---------------|--------------|
6  | Zurich   | Beth Bond     | Z1           |
7  | Zurich   | Fang Li       | Z2           |
8  | Zurich   | Garry Low     | Z3           |
```

I have tried using Foreach Loop Container, however it doesn't distinguish between provider. (btw, I have more than 50 providers to be split into different .csv files).

I'm using SQL Server 2012. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show your code that is not working?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM  Table1 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Provider
                    FROM  Table1) AS B ON A.Provider = B.Provider
ORDER BY A.Provider

Comment: I put above query into SSIS package (inside Execute SQL Task).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL, you don't need to use SSIS, it will work also, but here is how you can do it in SQL.

First make sure that the 'xp_cmdshell' is enabled.

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Using a cursor and the bcp.exe utility you can get the result you want

```
DECLARE @provider VARCHAR(255), @cmd VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT Provider FROM Test.dbo.ExportProvider          

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @provider

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "SELECT Id, Provider, AdviserName, PolicyNumber FROM Test.dbo.ExportProvider WHERE Provider = ''' + @provider + '''" queryout "C:\Temp\' + @provider + '.csv" -c -t, -C RAW -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
    EXECUTE xp_cmdShell @cmd
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @provider
END

CLOSE curs 
DEALLOCATE curs
```

This will result in 3 .csv files in the temp folder. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Great !!! it's working Kevin. Thanks for your help. I don't need to use SSIS package and its script anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the sample(s) below.  That will do what you want.

```
-- DROP TABLE Reporting_Table 
CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
       ID    varchar(10),
       IssueDate     Date,
       ExpirationDate    Date,
       Principal     Money,
       Interest  Money,
       Qtrs      Integer,
       Amount     Money)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('1232949523', '01/01/2017', '12/31/2019', 1000000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('1232949523', '03/05/2017', '12/31/2018', 5200000, .01, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('1232949523', '03/31/2017', '06/01/2020', 4900000, .015, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9567323294', '06/30/2017', '05/22/2019', 3500000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9567323294', '09/17/2017', '11/21/2022', 2000000, .02, Null, Null);

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9567323294', '01/01/2017', '12/31/2019', 1000000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9967949523', '03/05/2017', '12/31/2018', 5200000, .01, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9967949523', '03/31/2017', '06/01/2020', 4900000, .015, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9967949523', '06/30/2017', '05/22/2019', 3500000, .02, Null, Null); 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount)
VALUES ('9967949523', '09/17/2017', '11/21/2022', 2000000, .02, Null, Null);

SELECT ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, (Principal * Interest) As Amount
FROM Reporting_Table



select *, ntile(5) over(order by Principal) as tile_nr from Reporting_Table

Select *
From Reporting_Table


ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fxnExample (@Parameter1 NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT ID, IssueDate, ExpirationDate, Principal, Interest, Qtrs, Amount
    FROM Reporting_Table
    WHERE id = @Parameter1
)


-- Usage Example
SELECT * FROM dbo.fxnExample('1232949523')   -- only data from '1'
SELECT * FROM dbo.fxnExample('9567323294')   -- only data from '2'
SELECT * FROM dbo.fxnExample('9967949523')   -- only data from '3'


-- SPLIT A TABLE INTO EQUAL HALFS


select *, ntile(2) over(order by ID) as tile_nr from Reporting_Table
```